# Click sound in Chicago's song

Tags: recording, bands, sound-quality

Every time I listen to Chicago's "If you leave me now" song in the beginning 00:09 I hear a slight click sound. I guess it's natural sound of guitar strings touched while changing the chord. But I'm not sure. Can anybody explain the origin of that sound?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the single click on the left, before the F# establishes itself, rather than the repeating tick on the right, which is hi-hat pedal?
The more I listen to that it simply sounds like a mistake. It's string-slap, literally slapping the strings with the heel or flat of your hand, & it does fit the rhythmic meter of the rest of the guitar part, but it's just a bit late to sound completely intentional.

I guess the only way to know whether it was intended or not would be to ask the guitarist ;)

Just as an example with lots of string slap, this track sprung to mind. It has no other relevance, just a really good example of what string slap sounds like
[John Mayer - Neon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-bZFAnLzjs)
It covers both types, thumb & heel of palm hitting just the strings & also full flat palm hitting strings & body.